# What to do with a bricked router?

Tags: wireless-router, arch-linux, networkmanager, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I bought an used router from a friend, it seem bricked, is there something I could do to make it work ???

I'm using Archlinux, network-manager don't seem to connect to it ...

Linksys WRT300N (Cisco) [pre-N]

What make me assume that it may be bricked :
The power led is semi lit, all others are lit but wireless and security leds aren't lit ...

Comment: Have you tried other things besides connecting to it via network manager?  It might not be truly bricked.

Comment: I don't know how to connect to it by the command line, do you know how ?

Comment: Be good to the environment.  Recycle.

Answer (score 2):

Well, pretty much the solution to try is to find the [jtag port, make a jtag cable connecting a router to a parallel](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=328200#328200) , and use that to debrick the system. You will also need the software from [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/JTAG).

The software is windows only, and you'll need a system with a serial port (probably a desktop) to fix this.

Comment: Maybe the only way but the router seem like new, peoples in my town are noobs, I don't think it could be bricked but never say never ...

Comment: You might also want to try a wired connection. Without knowing what was done to the system, its hard to tell

Comment: What do you think I'm trying, I don't ask to configurate it by wifi, it don't connect to the router so I can't use 192.168.1.1 ...

Comment: it may not be 192.168.1.1 - i've seen 192.168.0.1 and .0.254 as router addresses.  I don't have much information to go on from the question, but thats something i'd try too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the hard reset button should work? Nearly every router/switch I came across had it... (press it for 15+ seconds when it's powered on, Edimaxes have even 30s timeout).

EDIT:

http://compnetworking.about.com/b/2009/03/11/the-30-30-30-hard-reset-rule-for-routers.htm

> After a long period absolutely “dead” my WRT300N is back to activitie.
>   Thank you so much !!! Regards, M@Rio

But since you said you've tried it and it didn't... I will leave it here for other people with this problem.

Comment: Tried the 30/30/30 hard reset, the led should have blinked or something, right ?

Comment: I just googled and found http://seoroot.com/blog/networking/wrt300n-and-wpc300n-faqs.html, where they say 30s press should be enough. Don't know about blinking, every manufacturer signalizes it differently. @JourneymanGeek 's answer looks more appropriate, mine is just a guess :)